# How do you remove a CSS class from a certain element of a list with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to remove a CSS class from a specific item when clicking on that item's button. Removing the CSS class will make a menu appear. How would I go about doing this with React? Here's the code.

```
import "./Homepage.css"
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
// import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
// import { faArrowDown } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import useFetch from "./useFetch"
import Axios from "axios"

export default function Homepage() {
  const [body, setBody] = useState("")
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState("")
  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  const [css, setCss] = useState("")
  const [flash, setFlash] = useState(null)
  const posts = useFetch("http://localhost:5000/api/data")
  const firstRender = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    let test = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user"))
    console.log(test)
    setData(posts)
  }, [posts])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false
      return
    }
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)
    })
    setSortedData(data)
  }, [data])

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/react-create-post", { text: body }, { withCredentials: true })
      .then((res) => {
        setSortedData((prevArray) => [res.data.post, ...prevArray])
        setFlash("Successfully created post.")
        setCss("success-msg")
        setBody("")
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setCss("error-msg")
        setFlash("Field cannot be left blank.")
      })
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.target.parentElement.children[1]
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <div className="create-container">
          <div className="posts-title">Create Post</div>
          <form id="theForm" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
            <textarea onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)} value={`${body}`} id="theInput" className="post-input" name="text" type="text"></textarea>
            <button className="submit-btn">POST</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div id="postsContainer" className="posts-container">
          <div className="posts-title">Latest Posts</div>
          {flash ? <div className={css}>{flash}</div> : console.log()}
          <div id="postInput">
            {sortedData &&
              sortedData.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <div className="post-container" key={item._id}>
                    <Link className="a" to={`/user/${item.author}`}>
                      <h3 className="author">{item.author}</h3>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="date">{item.date.toLocaleString()}</div>
                    <div className="options-cont">
                      <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} id="optionsBtn" className="options-btn">
                        <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button data-author={`${item.author}`} data-id={`${item._id}`} data-text={`${item.body}`} id="editBtn" className="edit inside-btn invisible">
                        Edit
                      </button>
                      <button data-author={`${item.author}`} data-id={`${item._id}`} id="deleteBtn" className="delete inside-btn invisible">
                        Delete
                      </button>
                      <br></br>
                    </div>
                    <p className="body-text">{item.body}</p>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  )
}
```

As far as I'm concerned using state as the className would remove or alter the CSS of each item in the "sortedData" array and make the menus for all items appear. I only want the menu for one of the items to appear.

Comment: This is a good moment to break the elements out into their own component, which will forego needing to store item data as data-attributes, but instead as state within each item (or lifted to the parent if need be).

Comment: What class? On what element?  (`e.target.parentElement.children[1]` will either be the edit button or `undefined`, depending on where within the button the user clicks.) And are you using class components or hooks?

Answer (score 1):

As [pilchard said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786102/how-do-you-remove-a-css-class-from-a-certain-element-of-a-list-with-react#comment123354741_69786102), you probably want to make each of those its own component with its own "showing" state, or at least "showing" prop.

> As far as I'm concerned using state as the className would remove or alter the CSS of each item in the "sortedData" array and make the menus for all items appear. I only want the menu for one of the items to appear.

That would be true if you used a **single** flag in state. But instead, use a **set** of flags, one flag for each menu, perhaps keyed by `item._id`.

Assuming you don't do the refactoring pilchard (and I) suggest:

You haven't shown us enough code for me to know whether you're using class components or function components, so I'm going to guess function components with hooks. If so, the initial state would be:

```
const [showing, setShowing] = useState(new Set());
```

Then when rendering, you'd assign the class:

```
<theElement className={showing.has(item._id) ? "class-if-any-to-show-it" : "class-if-any-to-not-show-it" ...
```

To toggle, in the button pass the ID:

```
<button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, item._id)}
```

and then update state as appropriate:

```
const handleClick = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setShowing(showing => {
        showing = new Set(showing);
        if (showing.has(id)) {
            showing.delete(id);
        } else {
            showing.add(id);
        }
        return showing;
    });
};
```