# Display the description of a react product

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm having a little trouble with this function. I want that when the user clicks on the icon the product description is displayed. But when I click all the descriptions of the whole basket is displayed. In my function I used filter but it doesn't work. Who can tell what is wrong with my code? thank you very much

Solution :

```
const ViewMenu = (id) => {
        panier.map(t=> {
            if(t.id === id.id){
                setViewId(t.id)
                return setShow(!show)
            }else{
                return null
            }
        })     
    };
<div>
{
  show  ?
  <div>
    { 
      viewId === paniers.id ?
  <div> 
     <p >Sandwich : { paniers.burger }</p>
     <p className='panier-text_menu'>Accompagnement : { paniers.accompagnement }</p>
  <p className='panier-text_menu'>Boisson : { paniers.boisson }</p>  
 </div> 
 : null

}
</div>
 : null
}
</div>
```

```
const Panier = () =>{
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
  const viewMenu = (item) =>{
        
         panier.filter(t=> {
            if(t.id === item.id){
                return setShow(!show)
            }else{
                 return setShow(false)
             }
        })
  return(    
    <div className='container_command'>
        {panier.map((paniers) => 
            <ul className='listBurgerPanier' key={paniers.id}>
                <div className='container_command_panier_image'>
                    <img className='container_command_panier_images' src= {paniers.image} />
                </div>
                <div className='panier-text'>
                                
                    paniers.produit === "menuBurgerComplet" ? 
                        <div> 
                            <div>
                                <p>Menu { paniers.burger }</p>
                                    <div>
                                        <p className='panier-text_menu'>{ parseFloat(paniers.prix * paniers.quantite).toFixed(2) } €</p>
                                        {/* <button onClick={()=> viewMenu(paniers.id)}><GrView /></button>setShow(!show) */}
                                        <button onClick={()=> viewMenu}><GrView /></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                            {
                                    show === true ? 
                                <div>           
                                    <p className='panier-text_menu'>Sandwich : { paniers.burger }</p>
                                    <p className='panier-text_menu'>Accompagnement : { paniers.accompagnement }</p>
                                    <p className='panier-text_menu'>Boisson : { paniers.boisson }</p> 
                                </div>
                                : " "
                            }
                        </div>     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>  
        )}       
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: You can't use just *one* flag for this, because you have multiple descriptions. See [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786102/how-do-you-remove-a-css-class-from-a-certain-element-of-a-list-with-react) -- basically, use a `Set` of flags, not just one flag.

Comment: *(I didn't dupehammer it because while **I** think the [target question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786102/how-do-you-remove-a-css-class-from-a-certain-element-of-a-list-with-react) is a valid original for this question, it's not a canonical one [is there a canonical?] and I'm keenly aware that the only answer to it is mine. :-D )*

Comment: Alternatively, if you only want one thing visible at a time, you could store the selected ID, and compare it to the current item where you currently have `show === true`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DBS I tried this solution, it did not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @t.j Crowder I tried this solution, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following array:

```
const [panier, setPanier] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            image: 'image-url',
            produit: 'menuBurgerComplet',
            burger: 'burger',
            prix: 2,
            quantite: 3,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            image: 'image-url',
            produit: 'new menuBurgerComplet',
            burger: 'another burger',
            prix: 2,
            quantite: 3,
        },
    ]);
```

use UseEffect to add show key for each element:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const clonedPanier = cloneDeep(panier);

        clonedPanier.forEach((el) => {
            el.show = false;
        });
        setPanier(clonedPanier);
    }, []);
```

Update viewMenu function as follow:

```
const viewMenu = (id) => {
        const clonedPanier = cloneDeep(panier);

        clonedPanier.forEach((el) => {
            if (el.id === id) {
                el.show = !el.show;
            } else {
                el.show = false;
            }
        });
        setPanier(clonedPanier);
    };
```

Update your code as follow:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Menu { paniers.burger }</p>
        <div>
            <p className='panier-text_menu'>{ parseFloat(paniers.prix * paniers.quantite).toFixed(2) } €</p>
            <button onClick={() => viewMenu(paniers.id)}><GrView /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        {
            paniers.show ?
                <div>
                    <p className='panier-text_menu'>Sandwich : { paniers.burger }</p>
                    <p className='panier-text_menu'>Accompagnement : { paniers.accompagnement }</p>
                    <p className='panier-text_menu'>Boisson : { paniers.boisson }</p>
                </div>
                : " "
        }
    </div>
```

**Note**:

- cloneDeep is from lodash

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AdamMorsi. I tried the solution it does not work. I tried to work and do with what you sent me I failed